# How to make .net 8.0 hosting bundle take effect in Windows based docker containers

Tags: docker-image, .net-8.0, windows-container, windows-hosting

I have a .net 6.0 web App which is containerized by windows based docker image, and it worked good.
But when I migrate my APP to .net 8.0, and modified corresponding settings in Dockerfile, my App always throw error **HTTP Error 500.0 - ASP.NET Core IIS hosting failure (in-process)**
But all codes work good when I deploy them on-primese using IIS in Windows Server 2016.

My Dockerfile is as bellow:

```
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis AS final
    SHELL ["powershell"]
    EXPOSE 80 443

    RUN Invoke-WebRequest 'https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/7f4d5cbc-4449-4ea5-9578-c467821f251f/b9b19f89d0642bf78f4b612c6a741637/dotnet-runtime-8.0.0-win-x64.exe' -UserAgent '' -OutFile "C:/dotnet-runtime.exe"
    RUN Start-Process -FilePath "c:/dotnet-runtime.exe" -ArgumentList @('/install', '/q', '/norestart', 'OPT_NO_RUNTIME=1', 'OPT_NO_SHAREDFX=1') -Wait -PassThru

    RUN Invoke-WebRequest 'https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/2a7ae819-fbc4-4611-a1ba-f3b072d4ea25/32f3b931550f7b315d9827d564202eeb/dotnet-hosting-8.0.0-win.exe' -UserAgent '' -OutFile "C:/dotnet-hosting.exe"
    RUN Start-Process -FilePath "c:/dotnet-hosting.exe" -ArgumentList @('/install', '/q', '/norestart', 'OPT_NO_RUNTIME=1', 'OPT_NO_SHAREDFX=1') -Wait -PassThru

    # Copy the build artifacts
    ADD MyApp /inetpub/wwwroot
```

What's wrong with my installing on hosting bundle of .net 8? But it work good for .net 6, is there any break changes for .net 8 on hosting bundle?(I find nothing by now)

Comment: Question: Why are you using the ServerCore image? Why not the dotnet image that comes with it already? mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:8.0-windowsservercore-ltsc2022